# Proof of the existence of time-varying coefficients of eigenvectors to form a linear system of ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

I have a linear system of differential equations:

$$
\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t) + Bu(t), \quad x(0) = x_0, \quad \forall t \geq 0.
$$

We have $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. The dot notation denotes a derivative with respect to time $t$.

Let $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ be a set of linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n\}$ of $A$.

I want to **show that there exist functions** $\alpha_i(t)$ and $\beta_i(t)$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$ such that

$$
x(t) = \alpha_1(t)v_1 + \dots + \alpha_n(t)v_n, \qquad \qquad Bu(t) = \beta_1(t)v_1 + \dots + \beta_n(t)v_n.
$$

**Attempt:**

Since $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the set of $n$ eigenvectors are linearly independent, they span $\mathbb{R}^n$ and thus form a basis.

Thus, for any $t$, including $t = 0$, it can be represented as a linear combination  $x(t) = \alpha_1(t)v_1 + \dots + \alpha_n(t)v_n$. (**Can I say this?**)

If we take the derivative with respect to time, we have:

$$
\dot{x}(t) = \dot{\alpha}_1(t)v_1 + \dots + \dot{\alpha}_n(t)v_n
$$

Also, since they are eigenvectors, we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Ax(t) &= A[\alpha_1(t)v_1 + \dots + \alpha_n(t)v_n] \\
      &= \alpha_1(t)\lambda_1v_1 + \dots + \alpha_n(t)\lambda_2v_n
\end{aligned}
$$

But $\dot{x}(t)$ also satisfies the equation:
$$
\dot{x}(t) = Ax + Bu
$$

Thus, subtracting the second equation $Ax$ from the first equation $\dot{x}(t)$, we have:
$$
Bu(t) = \dot{x}(t) - Ax(t) = [\dot{\alpha}_1(t) - \lambda_1\alpha_1(t)]v_1 + \dots + [\dot{\alpha}_n(t) - \lambda_n\alpha_n(t)]v_n, 
$$
where $\beta_1(t) = \dot{\alpha}_1(t) - \lambda_1\alpha_1(t), \dots, \beta_n(t) = \dot{\alpha}_n(t) - \lambda_n\alpha_n(t)$.

I am unsure if the above proof attempted is correct, can anyone please check and point out any false logic?

Comment: Your proof looks perfectly fine, but I suspect it could be made simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks fine. Here's an alternative proof.

Let $P$ denote the matrix whose columns are $v_1,\dots,v_n$. Let $\alpha_i(t)$ denote the entries of the vector $\alpha(t) = P^{-1}x(t)$. We observe that
$$
\begin{align}
x(t) &= (PP^{-1})x(t) = P(P^{-1}x(t)) 
\\ & = \pmatrix{v_1 & \cdots & v_n} \pmatrix{\alpha_1(t)\\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n(t)} = \alpha_1(t)v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n v_n.
\end{align}
$$
Define $\beta_i(t)$ to be the entries of the vector $\beta(t) = P^{-1}Bu(t)$. By a similar argument to the above, we can show that $Bu(t) = \beta_1(t) v_1 + \cdots + \beta_n(t) v_n.$